# My app have no dynos. Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

my app doesn't works. Error:
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I went in heroku settings and I saw that this app have no dynos. How can I reset the dynos on heroku server.

Thx :)

Comment: "...check your logs for details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually increase the number of dynos for your app by dragging the web dyno bar in your Heroku settings to at least one. If that doesn't work, you may have written something incorrectly in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) if you have one.

Comment: so, in heroku / app / Resources don't show more the options to increase dynos! Others apps show normarly.

Comment: If you're having an actual technical problem with Heroku, you'll need to contact Heroku directly.